# Wait on interactive "Enter-PSSession -Session $session" to end before continuing in calling PowerShell Script?

Tags: powershell, remoting

I needed to send a setup script called Profile.ps1 to a remote computer before invoking Enter-PSSession.  The problem is when I open up the Session using New-PSSession, instead of calling each Remoting command with "-computer" this changes the commands from blocking mode to non-blocking mode and the script keeps executing without blocking.  How can I wait for the Enter-PSSession to end to block the script from doing the next task before the current task is finished, naming Enter-PSSession? Here is my code:

FILE: profile.ps1

```
write-host "Sourcing Profile: begin"
write-host "Sourcing Profile: done"
```

FILE: run.ps1

```
$comp = "myhost"

$session = New-PSSession  -Computer $comp 
Invoke-Command  -Session $session -FilePath C:\scripts\profile.ps1
Enter-PSSession  -Session $session
## HOW TO WAIT HERE until user types "exit" in interactive 
session?
write-host "done."
```

OUTPUT:

```
PS> .\run.ps1
Sourcing Profile: begin
Sourcing Profile: done
done.   #<===== Wrong Place
[myhost]: PS C:\Users\dude>
[myhost]: PS C:\Users\dude>
[myhost]: PS C:\Users\dude> exit
PS>    ## <==== done. message should be here instead  
PS>
```

This should work... except, Powershell doesn't provide an "-AsJob" flag for Enter-PSSession

```
$j = Enter-PSSession -Session $x -Asjob
Wait-Job $j
```

However, this works:

```
$x = New-PSSession  -Computer $comp 
Invoke-Command  -Session $x -FilePath C:\scripts\profile.ps1
$j = Invoke-Command -Session $x -Asjob  -FilePath ".\MyScript"
Wait-Job $j
Receive-Job $j
```

And this works:

```
$x = New-PSSession  -Computer $comp 
Invoke-Command  -Session $x -FilePath C:\scripts\profile.ps1
$j = Invoke-Command -Session $x -Asjob  -ScriptBlock $sb
Wait-Job $j
Receive-Job $j
```

Comment: "I needed to send a setup script called Profile.ps1 to a remote computer before invoking Enter-PSSession." - consider setting up a custom endpoint on the remote server - this way you can have [a setup script run automatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/register-pssessionconfiguration?view=powershell-7.1#example-2--register-a-maintenanceshell-session-configuration) everytime a user connects

Comment: I like having the profile.ps1 file stored with my remoting script... its less hassle than keeping the profile.ps1 on each computer.